# One-page-layout easing not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, easing

I'm having troubles in getting my one-page-layout anchor-links working in Internet Explorer.

I'm using jQuery with the Easing plugin to go to an anchor on my webpage, this works in Chrome, and when I tested it out in Internet Explorer (9), this happened:

Internet Explorer gave a warning on the bottom of the page that an ActiveX-element needs to be enabled, when I click on one of my links then, I get taken to the anchor, but without the animation (and it also comes up wrong, as I'm using a fixed header).

When I activate the ActiveX-element, nothing happens at all when I click on the link.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('ul.nav a, .top-logo a').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);
            var $section = $($anchor.attr('href'));
            if(!$section.length){ return } 

            $('body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $section.offset().top-139
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

            event.preventDefault();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Could anyone help me out with this?

Cheers!